# Is it possible to change Autosearch field from hard-coded 'suggestions' to data from database?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, mongodb, express

I found a whole code for hard-coded data autofill-search-field. It was doing great till the moment I realized that I have to connect my database to it. Im at the end of MERN project(first one ever) and I don't know how can I pass data stored in database(I just wanna pass the first name and second name here).

```
import AutocompleteFunc from './AutocompleteFunc';

  export default class Autocomplete extends Component {
   render() {
    return (
        <div style = {{position: "relative", top: "-60px", fontSize: '16px', right: "0px", width: 
    "150px", zIndex: 1}}>
       <AutocompleteFunc
    suggestions={[
  "Dawid",
  "Test Employee",
    ]}
  />
</div>
    )
  }
}
```

And the function for it:

```
 import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
 import PropTypes from "prop-types";
 import './AutocompleteFunccss.css'

 class AutocompleteFunc extends Component {
          static propTypes = {
            suggestions: PropTypes.instanceOf(Array)
          };

          static defaultProps = {
            suggestions: []
          };

          constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
              // The active selection's index
              activeSuggestion: 0,
              // The suggestions that match the user's input
              filteredSuggestions: [],
              // Whether or not the suggestion list is shown
              showSuggestions: false,
              // What the user has entered
              userInput: ""
            };
          }

          // Event fired when the input value is changed
          onChange = e => {
            const { suggestions } = this.props;
            const userInput = e.currentTarget.value;

            // Filter our suggestions that don't contain the user's input
            const filteredSuggestions = suggestions.filter(
              suggestion =>
                suggestion.toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput.toLowerCase()) > -1
            );

            // Update the user input and filtered suggestions, reset the active
            // suggestion and make sure the suggestions are shown
            this.setState({
              activeSuggestion: 0,
              filteredSuggestions,
              showSuggestions: true,
              userInput: e.currentTarget.value
            });
          };

          // Event fired when the user clicks on a suggestion
          onClick = e => {
            // Update the user input and reset the rest of the state
            this.setState({
              activeSuggestion: 0,
              filteredSuggestions: [],
              showSuggestions: false,
              userInput: e.currentTarget.innerText
            });
          };

          // Event fired when the user presses a key down
          onKeyDown = e => {
            const { activeSuggestion, filteredSuggestions } = this.state;

            // User pressed the enter key, update the input and close the
            // suggestions
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
              this.setState({
                activeSuggestion: 0,
                showSuggestions: false,
                userInput: filteredSuggestions[activeSuggestion]
              });
            }
            // User pressed the up arrow, decrement the index
            else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
              if (activeSuggestion === 0) {
                return;
              }

              this.setState({ activeSuggestion: activeSuggestion - 1 });
            }
            // User pressed the down arrow, increment the index
            else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
              if (activeSuggestion - 1 === filteredSuggestions.length) {
                return;
              }

              this.setState({ activeSuggestion: activeSuggestion + 1 });
            }
          };

          render() {
            const {
              onChange,
              onClick,
              onKeyDown,
              state: {
                activeSuggestion,
                filteredSuggestions,
                showSuggestions,
                userInput
              }
            } = this;

            let suggestionsListComponent;

            if (showSuggestions && userInput) {
              if (filteredSuggestions.length) {
                suggestionsListComponent = (
                  <ul class="suggestions">
                    {filteredSuggestions.map((suggestion, index) => {
                      let className;

                      // Flag the active suggestion with a class
                      if (index === activeSuggestion) {
                        className = "suggestion-active";
                      }

                      return (
                        <li
                          className={className}
                          key={suggestion}
                          onClick={onClick}
                        >
                          {suggestion}
                        </li>
                      );
                    })}
                  </ul>
                );
              } else {
                suggestionsListComponent = (
                  <div class="no-suggestions">
                    <em>No suggestions, you're on your own!</em>
                  </div>
                );
              }
            }

            return (
              <Fragment>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  onChange={onChange}
                  onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
                  value={userInput}
                />
                {suggestionsListComponent}
              </Fragment>
            );
          }
        }

        export default AutocompleteFunc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Api to provide `suggestions` source data and use it in  `<AutocompleteFunc
    suggestions={**names from api**}
  />`

and of course its not good solution for to many names

Check this [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/auto-search-field-from-database-zcudn)

Comment: Is there any way to make a connection between this component and database? Like literally point "TAKE DATA FROM HERE' like you did here?

Comment: No. You should get this data through the HTTP requests